# Best practice in getting name props in options inside onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get the `name` props value in my selected option. How can I get it?

```
constructor(props) {
  this.onChangeField = this.onChangeField.bind(this);
}

onChangeField(e) {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const name = e.target.name;
  console.log(value)                 // 1234
  console.log(name).                 // no value printed
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={this.onChangeField}>
        <option name='abcd' value ='1234' key='1234'>Option 1</option>
        <option name='wxyz' value ='9876' key='9876'>Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi Clement!
Did you have a chance to check my answer? My answer will works for you. You should use `getAttribute('name')` instead of `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your onChangeField function as like below.

```
onChangeField(e) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const name = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex]?.getAttribute('name');
    console.log(value)                 // 1234
    console.log(name)                 // will print correct value
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a reference to the selected option.  Right now you have `e.target` which is the `<select>`

```
onChangeField(e) {
  const select = e.target;
  const selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex]; // there are a few ways to do this
  const value = select.value; // or selectedOption.value, the select gets the value property of its selected option
  const name = selectedOption.name;
  console.log(value);                 // 1234
  console.log(name);                 // should be correct
}
```

Comment: thanks loads. This actually worked with some minor change. Namely, 
 changing name to equate selectedOption.getAttribute('name') instead